# edit bash script to truncate leading numbers on files when creating folders

Tags: bash-scripting

```
for file in *; do
  if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
    mkdir "${file%.*}"
    mv "$file" "${file%.*}"
  fi
done
```

So I will have tons of files that will look like "012345_randomnameoffile.pdf" and I want to edit this script to create a folder name of just the numbers and move the file into the folder after creation but if that folder already exists just move the file into the folder. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The answer to part of your question can be found in the `mkdir` man page.   I don't understand the rest of the question.

Comment: so as it stands this script will do a one to one creation of a folder for each file with the same name and put that file in the folder. I want this script to only create folders with the numbers as the folder name and put any file that starts with those numbers into the same folder.

Comment: OK, does *every* file have a name that begins with one or more digits (number characters)  immediately followed by one (or more) space(s)?

Answer (score 1):

Found it

```
for file in *; do mkdir -p -- "${file%%_*}" && \
mv -- "${file}" "${file%%_*}/${file#*_}"; done
```

This is basically what I wanted with the added bonus of renaming the file and removing the case number prefix.

Comment: How would I represent a space in this script instead of an _ ? I edited everything to try to make it all more consistent.

Comment: Pretty straightforward: `"${file%% *}"`. There's a bug in this script: `${file##*_}` should be `${file#*_}` in case there is more than one `_` in the filename. It may not matter in your specific case but in general one may lose fragments of names because of the bug.

Comment: I appreciate it, you might have just saved me a considerable amount of headache